# Spring + Ehcache : Not able to get the cache back from cacheManager without key

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, spring-3

I am using Spring + Ehcache for my cache layer and it is working. But for some reason I wanna manipulate the cache manually.

```
@Cacheable(value = "productAll")
public List<Product> getAllProduct()

@CacheEvict(value = "product", key = "#product.id")
public Product saveProduct(Product product) 

@Cacheable(value = "product")
public Product getProductById(Long id)
```

This works fine, but when I try to manually update the productAll cache in the saveProduct function. I am not able to get the cache back from the cache manager

```
Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("productAll");
cache.get("");
```

What is the key that I should use in this case, when no key is provided when we cache in the getProductAll method?

Answer (score 3):

None of the above solutions worked for me, but using SimpleKey.EMPTY did:

```
Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("productAll");
cache.get(SimpleKey.EMPTY);
```

From https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-integration/cache-key-generation.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("productAll");
cache.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("productAll");
cache.get(0).get();
```